# How to Convert Data Type Number to dd:hh:mm:ss in Oracle after sum

Tags: oracle

I am trying to convert Number value (data type - `Number`) to `dd:hh:mm:ss` after doing summation in Oracle. For example, I have a table where value like below. here Values are stored as seconds.

```
ID   Value
----------------------
001  125698
002  5698233
001  896398233
```

From above value, i want to sum value for ID **001** and convert into dd:hh:mm:ss. How will i do ? Please assist.

Comment: You need to explain what does this number mean.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you find [NUMTODSINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm) function useful.  Example (Oracle 11g)

```
-- test table: NUMBERS
create table numbers ( id_, value_ ) as
select '001',    125698 from dual union all
select '002',   5698233 from dual union all
select '001', 896398233 from dual ;
```

> i want to sum value for ID 001 and convert into dd:hh:mm:ss

```
select 
  numtodsinterval( sum( value_ ), 'second' ) 
from numbers
where id_ = '001'
;

-- result
NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM(VALUE_),'SECOND')  
+10376 10:25:31.000000
```

You can [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) the days/hours/minutes/seconds from the result, and add some ':' characters by using the concatenation operator.

```
select
  extract( day from interval_ )    || ':' ||
  extract( hour from interval_ )   || ':' ||
  extract( minute from interval_ ) || ':' ||
  extract( second from interval_ ) dhms
from (
  select 
    numtodsinterval( sum( value_ ), 'second' ) interval_
  from numbers
  where id_ = '001'
)
;

-- result
DHMS            
10376:10:25:31
```

see also: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e38e0c2b9054f3a1148447e739e8a21)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't some simple way to derive this. However we can calculate the days, hours, minutes and seconds by applying a mix of `floor()` and `mod()` calls, like this:

```
select id
       , value
       , floor(value / 86400) as days
       , floor(mod(value, 86400) / 3600) as hours
       , floor(mod(value, 3600) / 60) as mins
       , mod(value, 60) as secs
from your_table
```